# gridview using datatable in asp.net is not show every column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

here is my aspx code:

```
  <div class="box-body">

        <asp:GridView ID="gvSms" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

here is my cs code:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Master.pageHeaderTitle = "Employee Sms";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Employee Code");
            dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Mobile No");
            dt.Columns.Add("Message");
            dt.Columns.Add("Creating Date");
            var db = new HRContext();
            var data=db.EmployeeSms.Where(d => d.HasRead == false).OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).ToList();
            if(data!=null)
            {
                foreach(var item in data)
                {
                    string mobile = item.EmployeeMobile.TrimStart('8').TrimStart('8');
                    var emp = db.Employee.Where(d => d.OfficePhone == mobile).FirstOrDefault();
                    string code = "";
                    string name = "";
                    if(emp!=null)
                    {
                        code = emp.eployeId;
                        name = emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(code,name,item.EmployeeMobile,item.SMS,item.CreatedAt);
                }
            }

            gvSms.DataSource = dt;
            gvSms.DataBind();

        }
```

using this code creating date column is not shown because of  long message in one line. if message column make comment out then it shown. So how can i fixed this? is it make message column multiline or make gridview scrollable. i tried but can't.
Any kind of help is appreciable and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is max length of string you have in Message Column? Also what do you mean by 'I tried but can't' ? Are you unable to show gridview scrollable or even scrollable grid unable to show the Date column?

Comment: thanks for your comment @SivaGopal . i tried to make message column multi line but i can not make it. full message shown in a single line as result next column can not visible.string length define varchar(255) in sql table.

Comment: Can you post some sample screenshot of your problem. Any width you are setting through css/aspx and any panels inside which this grid was enclosed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have set the data type of Date column to `DateTime` or `varchar` in Database and then use:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
dt.Rows.Add(code,name,item.EmployeeMobile,item.SMS,date);
```